# How to cut the first part of a string and store it

Tags: c#, .net

I have a txt file with lines starting with a random character follewed by 7 numbers like this:

- A1234567 - random
- E2345678 - random
- D5423434 - random

I want to copy the first 8 chracters from every line and store them for the reason to make a txt file containing only the needed part of the starting one.

I found out that the Substring method could work, I just don't know how to make an array out of them.

It would help me a lot if someone could help me out.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried? Then highlight the bit you can't get to work and we can take a look. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When querying, try using *Linq*:

```
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 string[] result = File
   .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt")
 //.Where(line => line.Length >= 8) // uncomment if you want to remove short lines
   .Select(line => line.Length >= 8 
      ? line.Substring(0, 8) 
      : line)
   .ToArray();
```

In case you want to *ensure* that the line starts with the *pattern* (capital letter followed by 7 digits) you can try *regular expression*:

```
  using System.IO;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string[] result = File
    .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt")
    .Select(line => Regex.Match(line, "^[A-Z][0-9]{7}"))
    .Where(match => match.Success)
    .Select(match => match.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

To write date to the file use `File.WriteAllLines`:

```
  File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\cleared.txt", result);
```

Comment: You could use `File.WriteAllLines` to write out the `IEnumerable<string>` without loading the results in an array

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos: Agree, if "and store them for the reason to make a txt file" means "*immediately* write them into text file"

Comment: Thank you for all your detailed help! Much appreciated and thanks for showing me a new interesting way to solve the problem!